# Google GeoCoding API multiple search results

Tags: api, google-maps, geocode

Currently I am using the following URL to get the addresses and coordinates of a search string in my app.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=<Address>&sensor=false
```

The URL returns multiple results only when the  string is given in a particular format. For example, I am trying to search for a business named "Yashoda Hospital, Hyderabad" and the results give only one address although the same search string gives multiple results in Google Maps website. But when I enter the string with a slight variation ("Yashoda Hospitals, Hyderabad") by adding an 's', it returns two addresses.

Is there a particular URL through which we can get all the possible results? Or what should be the approach to capture all the possible addresses that are returned in Google Maps website?

Comment: What is you application context? Why are you using that URL and not the `Geocoder` service in the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)?

Comment: request [**places**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) instead of using the geocoder

Comment: The [geocoder](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Yashoda%20Hospital,%20Hyderabad&geocode=1) returns one result.  The [places API](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Yashoda%20Hospital,%20Hyderabad&place=1) returns 20 (the maximum allowed in a single request)